# Global variable can't be modified in a separate function

Tags: python

I am trying to make a simple RPS game and can't see what I am doing wrong.
I declare `pc_choise`, `player_choice` and `turns` as global variables but I can't modify them in functions such as `checkWinner()`.

If I print that value after the function has been called, it still has the initial value.

### Code:

```
import random
import sys

pc_choices = ['r','p','s']
pc_choise = ''
player_choice = ''
turns = 0

print("\t\tWelcome to Rock Paper Scissors")


def getPcChoice():
  return random.randint(1,3) - 1

def getUserChoice():

player_choice = input('Please choose: ')
turns = 1

if(player_choice.lower() not in pc_choices):
  print('\nPlease use R, P, or S -  *not case sensitive*\n')
  getUserChoice()
else:
  pc_choise = pc_choices[getPcChoice()]
  print('\nYou picked ' + player_choice + ' and the PC picked ' + 
  pc_choise)
  checkWinner()

def checkWinner():

  if(player_choice.lower() == pc_choise.lower()):
    print('Tie')
  elif(player_choice.lower() == 'r' and pc_choise.lower() == 'p'
    or   player_choice.lower() == 'p' and pc_choise.lower() == 's'
    or   player_choice.lower() == 's' and pc_choise.lower() == 'r'):
    print('You win! ')
  else:
    print('You lose! ')

 
getUserChoice()
```

Comment: If you want to modify a global variable within a function, you have to add `global player_choice` and `global pc_choise` to the top of the function.

Comment: Or even better- refactor your code to avoid global variables altogether. [Why are global variables evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)

Comment: `getUserChoice` could easily be modified to just return the choice instead of modifying the global.

Comment: @mario_sunny what should I be looking at when refactoring? Some major steps to follow?

Comment: @VladutMaican If you post this code on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions) as complete, runnable code, I or someone else can go over it and help improve it.

Answer (score 2):

add the following code in the first line of the code:

`global pc_choices` and `global pc_choice` etc.

this is to mark the variable will use is a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variables as `global` within the function scope so that Python interpreter can interpret them accordingly, otherwise, they get the function scope by default. I also found indentation issues which I have fixed. Below is your modified code:

```
import random
import sys

pc_choices = ['r','p','s']

pc_choise = ''
player_choice = ''
turns = 0

print("\t\tWelcome to Rock Paper Scissors")

def getPcChoice():
    return random.randint(1,3) - 1

def getUserChoice():
    global pc_choise
    global player_choice

    player_choice = input('Please choose: ')
    turns = 1

    if(player_choice.lower() not in pc_choices):
        print('\nPlease use R, P, or S -  *not case sensitive*\n')
        getUserChoice()
    else:
        pc_choise = pc_choices[getPcChoice()]
        print('\nYou picked ' + player_choice + ' and the PC picked ' + pc_choise)
        checkWinner()

def checkWinner():
    global pc_choise
    global player_choice

    if(player_choice.lower() == pc_choise.lower()):
        print('Tie')
    elif(player_choice.lower() == 'r' and pc_choise.lower() == 'p'
        or   player_choice.lower() == 'p' and pc_choise.lower() == 's'
        or   player_choice.lower() == 's' and pc_choise.lower() == 'r'):
        print('You win! ')
    else:
        print('You lose! ')

getUserChoice()
```

However, as suggested by @mario_sunny in the comments, it's better to avoid using global variables.